# WPF: How to combine Rows within a column (alternative to rowspan)?

Tags: wpf, gridview, layout, wpf-controls

Is there a way to combine rows within a specific column? Hence to get something like this (I am currently using rowspan on a control i.e. Image but is there a better way?)

```
    --------------------
    |         |--------|
    |         |--------|
    |         |--------|
    |         |--------|
    |         |--------|
    --------------------
```

I am using this code basically

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="124" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="246*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Which gives me something like this (notice the rows also appear in column 0)

```
    --------------------
    |---------|--------|
    |---------|--------|
    |---------|--------|
    |---------|--------|
    |---------|--------|
    --------------------
```

Now i can get around this for example if i want to place a image i can use RowSpan, but is it not possible to design a column with no rows and the other columns having rows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible with the `Grid` control. Rows pass through all columns, and columns pass through all rows. As you've found, the `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` allow you to have a control span multiple rows or columns respectively.

One other potential workaround is to host one `Grid` within another:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks kent, but i suppose the extra code bloat isn't worth it? .. I presume its better to continue using my grid and just use RowSpan etc?

Comment: @Mark: yeah, judging by your description I'd say `RowSpan` is the easiest way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Height="100" Width="50"></Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use rectangle to merge the 6 rows.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="124" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="246*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="6"/>
</Grid>
```